# Tomcat with Eclipse ClassNotfoundException in Vaadin Project (maven)

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin7, tomcat8

I'm developing a Vaadin project in Eclipse with Maven. The problem is that I get a ClassNotFoundException for my main class (UI). On the other hand, if I import the generated WAR file into Eclipse as another project, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. There are two active projects in eclipse in my situation. One is vaadin widget and the other one depends on it. The problem goes away when I close the widget project (after doing maven install).

PS: using Mars .2